# Toggle Div from right to left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle a div from left to right. The following code makes it toggle from top to bottom, but how can i make it toggle from left to right?

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('.slidewrap').slideToggle();    
  });    
})
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ovaqqata/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);

$(this).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```